Problem related to number of solutions
I was solving some questions where I found this question.
So here we just had to find solution of $\cos(\ln x)= \ln(\cos x)$ in interval $(e^{-π/2} , \frac{π}{2})$
As I saw number of solutions I tried graph as idk I feel graph in these type of questions, but the problem is that I was unable to even make graph:)
Any help would be appreciated:)

$\cos(\ln(x))$ is strictly positive on the interval, while $\ln(\cos(x)$ is strictly negative on the interval. Therefore there is no solution.
